# Composer behind proxy, set up, still not working

Tags: laravel, proxy, composer-php

I have VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 behind proxy. I've installed Apache2, PHP, MySQL and Composer. I did google, set up system wide proxy, proxy for apt-get and for git. And according to this:

```
deralsem@DerVirtualBox:/var/www/laravel$ composer diag
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking **HTTP proxy**: OK
Checking **HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri**: OK
Checking **HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri**: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

Composer is set up for proxy use. But, trying this:

```
$ cd /var/www
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
Navigate to Laravel code directory and use composer to install all dependencies required for Laravel framework.
$ cd /var/www/laravel
$ sudo composer install
```

i have this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                 
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname                       
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname                                                                        

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the `HTTP_PROXY` as environment variable

```
HTTP_PROXY='http://the.proxy'
export HTTP_PROXY
php composer.phar install
```

And maybe

```
HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0
export HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI
```

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy

(When the diagnose command is not reporting the environment issues correctly, it could be a Composer bug.)

---

The error message `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname` indicates a DNS problem.

It seems that the DNS resolving of the proxy is not properly configured.

Please try changing the name servers in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file to other nameservers, e.g. Google Inc., by appending one of their DNS server IPv4 addresses (resolv.conf(5)):

```
sudo printf '\nnameserver 8.8.8.8\n' >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then you might `ping` the URL and the IP address of Packagist.

Request URL (hostname): https://packagist.org/

Remote Address: 87.98.253.214:443

Comment: Tried that already - no luck, same error, no address associated with hostname.

Comment: Thats odd. I think its not a Composer, but a proxy / DNS configuration issue.